# How do i disable ui-grid events?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want that when i select all rows in a grid doesn't call the event rowSelectionChangedBatch, how do i do this?

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope, function() {
          /* Do something */
      });
}

/* More code */
function selectAll() {
    /* After execute this, should not call the event */
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectAllRows();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `selectAll` trigger `$event.stopPropagation();` like this:

> data-ng-click="grid.appScope.selectAll(); $event.stopPropagation();"